# UITableView section with UITextField cannot input text after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uitextfield

I have this weird problem.

My set up is this - a `UITableView` with a section view (returned in `viewForHeaderInSection`) that is a `UITextField`. Initially, the section has 0 rows.

If I just run the code as is, everything works. I can tap the `UITextField`, the cursor shows up, and text is entered.

Next, I want to make it so that when you tap on the section (i.e., the `UITextField`), I want to show additional rows. To do this, I listen to `textViewDidBeginEditing`.

In `textViewDidBeginEditing`, I set a state (which causes `numberOfRowsInSection` to return non-zero), and then I do `reloadData`.

I've tested and discovered that the call to `reloadData` causes weirdness. Specifically, after tapping on the `UITextField`, the cursor indicates the `UITextField` has focus and the keyboard pops up, but typing in the keyboard does not result in any text showing up in the `UITextField`.

If I remove the call to `reloadData`, typing results in text showing in the `UITextField`.

Does anyone know why calling `reloadData` causes weirdness with the input? I tried setting the `firstResponder` but it had no effect.

Comment: The Textfield is in the sectiontitle?

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu it's returned in `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: Then, when you start editing it. `textViewDidBeginEditing`is fired and your view is created again from scratch, wiping the recently made textentry. 
That's why it seems, that it does not accept input. It does, but the view is instantly replaced by a new one. 
Try firing the reloadData in `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu That makes sense - but in my `viewForHeaderInSection` I'm not returning a new view, but I create a view in `viewDidLoad` and return it even during a reload. Shouldn't that work? The reason why I want it in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is because I want to show rows that are filtered based on what is being typed (kind of like a filtered list).

Comment: Okay. You should try placing the texfield outside of the tableview in my opinion. Making it persistent over the reloadData calls in the tableview.
And at this point I do not know, if viewDidLoad actually gets called again with a reloadData

Comment: Try to use reloadSections on your UITableView instead of reloadData. Also, you could do a state check if the textField still had firstResponder when reloadData is called, give it firstResponder after the reloadData again. EDIT: you already tried that I see.. :)